# While entering the jpql query using @Query i am not getting any output? Can someone tell me whats wrong with the below query?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I am using this query

```
@Query("from Flight where departureCity = :departureCity and arrivalCity =:arrivalCity and dateOfDeparture =:dateOfDeparture")

List<Flight> findFlights(@Param("departureCity") String departureCity,@Param("arrivalCity") String arrivalCity,@Param("dateOfDeparture") Date dateOfTravel);
```

When i use the default crud operations like findAll then everything is printing but with above query nothing is displayed. I dont understand how above query works and what mistake i am making. Someone please help me in getting this right..
This is the output i get on the console

```
Hibernate: select flight0_.id as id1_0_, flight0_.arrival_city as arrival_2_0_, flight0_.date_of_departure as date_of_3_0_, flight0_.departure_city as departur4_0_, flight0_.estimated_departure_time as estimate5_0_, flight0_.flight_number as flight_n6_0_, flight0_.operating_airlines as operatin7_0_ from flight flight0_ where flight0_.departure_city=? and flight0_.arrival_city=? and flight0_.date_of_departure=?
```

**This is my MODEL CLASS**

```
private String flightNumber;
        private String operatingAirlines;
        private String departureCity;
        private String arrivalCity;
        private Date dateOfDeparture;
        private Timestamp estimatedDepartureTime;
```

**This is my CONTROLLER CLASS**

```
public String findflight(@RequestParam("departurecity")String departureCity, @RequestParam("arrivalcity")String arrivalCity, 
             @RequestParam("traveldate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date dateOfTravel, ModelMap model)
    {
        List<Flight> flight = flightRepo.findFlights(departureCity, arrivalCity, dateOfTravel);
        model.addAttribute("find",  flight);
        return "displayflights";
    }
```

**This is my JSP PAGE**

```
<th>Airlines</th>
        <th>Departure City</th>
        <th>Arrival City</th>
        <th>Departure Time</th>
      </tr>
     <c:forEach items="${find}" var="flight">
      <tr>
       <td>${flight.operatingAirlines}</td>
       <td>${flight.departureCity}</td>
       <td>${flight.arrivalCity}</td>
       <td>${flight.estimatedDepartureTime}</td>
       <td><a href="showCompleteReservation?Flightid=${flight.id}">select</a></td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: Try writing the full query in the @Query() annotation. Like, ```@Query("select f from Flight f where f.departureCity = :departureCity and f.arrivalCity =:arrivalCity and f.dateOfDeparture =:dateOfDeparture") ```

Comment: @DusayantaPrasad Tried this as well, still it is not showing any data!!

Comment: I have just been implementing something similar. Try to avoid namedParameter and it will just work fine. Something like
    @Query("select f.name from mytable f where f.ip= ?1 and f.arrivalcity= ?2")
    List<Flight> findflight(String departurecity, String arrivalcity);